# A word meaning "more related"

Tags: single-word-requests

> Nana travels to America to have a surgery done. One that could put an
>   end to her life-long affliction. But is her problem exclusive of her
>   body? Or is rather a condition **more related** to her soul?

What word could I use to replace **"more related"** in the passage above? I think the phrase *more related* won't have much impact in the reader.

(By the way, is **but** necessary in the second last sentence)?

Comment: It should be just "surgery", not "*a* surgery". "exclusive of her body" doesn't make sense. "But" is fine. Don't really know what you're trying to say. You could put "condition *of* her soul" - but that wouldn't be related to undergoing surgery.

Comment: There's no need for "done". The surgery itself takes care of that. The last part doesn't seem to be properly connected with the preceding sentence.

Comment: Plus, it would good to mention what type of surgery she is having. e.g, heart surgery, neck surgery, etc.

Comment: You could just say "Or is her condition psychosomatic?" since that is the word that means a condition that doesn't have a physical cause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest

> "Is Nana's affliction merely physical, or could there be an underlying spiritual component?"

Or,

> "Is Nana's affliction physical, or could it be more spiritual than physical?"

Or,

> "Is Nana's affliction only physical, or could it be related more to her soul than to her body?"

Any of the above could work.  The third example, though, includes the words *related* and *more*, albeit arranged differently.

Comment: Thanks! You also suggest removing the BUT?

Comment: Not necessarily.  That depends on how you want the various pieces to fit together.  For example, "To put an end to her lifelong affliction, Nana travelled to America.  The question* I kept asking myself was, "Is Nana's affliction purely physical, or could it be more spiritual than physical?"                                                     *or, "But the question . . .."